# pgfplotstable - siunitx error with data from csv with values in scientific notation

Tags: tables, siunitx, pgfplotstable, csv

I want to create table using pgfplotstable with data from csv file with values in scientific notation, but when i try to compile the file to pdf I end up with following siunitx errors

```
Package siunitx: Invalid numerical input '8.47e'.
Package siunitx: Invalid numerical input '2e'.
Package siunitx: Invalid numerical input '1.9e'.
Package siunitx: Invalid numerical input '2e'.
and so on...
```

Here is my code

```latex
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \begin{center}
            \pgfplotstabletypeset[
                col sep=comma,
                header=false,
                display columns/0/.style={
                    column name=$U_{led}$,
                    column type={S},
                    string type
                },
                display columns/1/.style={
                    column name=$I_{led}$,
                    column type={S},
                    string type
                },
                display columns/2/.style={
                    column name=$U_{det}$,
                    column type={S},
                    string type
                },
                every head row/.style={
                    before row={\toprule},
                    after row={{[\si{\volt}]} & {[\si{\milli\ampere}]} & {[\si{\volt}]}\\\midrule}
                },
                every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
            ]{../data/va_lux_char.csv}
            \label{table:va_lux}
            \caption{Tabulka}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
```

and here is my CSV file

```
0.646,8.47e-08,2e-06
1.11,1.9e-07,2e-06
1.288,2.96e-07,2e-06
1.388,6.97e-07,2e-06
1.413,9.93e-07,2e-06
1.456,1.99e-06,2e-06
1.479,3e-06,2e-06
1.526,6.99e-06,2e-06
1.545,9.99e-06,2e-06
1.581,2e-05,0.000124
1.602,3e-05,0.000384
1.644,7e-05,0.00231
1.698,0.0002,0.0141
1.718,0.0003,0.0249
1.765,0.0007,0.0639
1.788,0.001,0.0858
1.838,0.002,0.131
1.875,0.003,0.159
1.978,0.007,0.218
2.037,0.01,0.242
2.205,0.02,0.288
2.35,0.03,0.315
2.443,0.037,0.329
```

**EDIT:**
I found out the problem was in combination of siunitx and czech babel packege which uses `-` as active character, so usign `\shorthandoff{-}` above and `\shorthandon{-}` below the table solved the problem and now it works fine.

Comment: Please prepare a complete small example document, that allows others to reproduce the error messages you get. If I take your code fragments and create such a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) myself, I end up with a document, that compiles without error messages.

Comment: @fist -- welcome -- please have a look athe answer below if meets the requirement

Answer (score -1):

[image]

```
 \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx, pgfplots,array,booktabs,siunitx,}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{data1.csv}
    0.646,8.47e-08,2e-06
    1.11,1.9e-07,2e-06
    1.288,2.96e-07,2e-06
    1.388,6.97e-07,2e-06
    1.413,9.93e-07,2e-06
    1.456,1.99e-06,2e-06
    1.479,3e-06,2e-06
    1.526,6.99e-06,2e-06
    1.545,9.99e-06,2e-06
    1.581,2e-05,0.000124
    1.602,3e-05,0.000384
    1.644,7e-05,0.00231
    1.698,0.0002,0.0141
    1.718,0.0003,0.0249
    1.765,0.0007,0.0639
    1.788,0.001,0.0858
    1.838,0.002,0.131
    1.875,0.003,0.159
    1.978,0.007,0.218
    2.037,0.01,0.242
    2.205,0.02,0.288
    2.35,0.03,0.315
    2.443,0.037,0.329
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
     \begin{table}[h!]
        \begin{center}
            \pgfplotstabletypeset[
            col sep=comma,
            header=false,
            display columns/0/.style={
                column name=$U_{led}$,
                column type={S},
                string type
            },
            display columns/1/.style={
                column name=$I_{led}$,
                column type={S},
                string type
            },
            display columns/2/.style={
                column name=$U_{det}$,
                column type={S},
                string type
            },
            every head row/.style={
                before row={\toprule},
                after row={{[\si{\volt}]} & {[\si{\milli\ampere}]} & {[\si{\volt}]}\\\midrule}
            },
            every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
            ]{data1.csv}
            \label{table:va_lux}
            \caption{Tabulka}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```